# Retrieve data from large MongoDB in Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, performance

I want to retrieve some data from the MongoDB collection which contains 1M documents and is increasing daily.

I need the data some data at once for some specific purpose. However, My fetching data size is potentially low. Like 25-30K documents at once, however, I need to fetch the data given a date range.

I have tried several approaches, The closer approach to DB I have tried is

```
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => [
                            'created_at' => [
                                '$gte' => $from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                '$lte' => $to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$project' => [
                            'user_id' => 1,
                            'created_at' => 1,
                            'checked_out_at' => 1,
                            'department.name' => 1,
                            'department.address' => 1,
                            '_id' => 0,
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        '$sort' => [
                            'user_id' => 1,
                            'created_at' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);
            });
```

I am getting responses from small collections with these codes but didn't for large ones.
I have tried these with MongoDB compass(Picture below), and these filters give me data within 350ms from the large database as well. But why it is not working while I am using it in Laravel?
Thank you for your valuable time.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issues.
The MongoDB can process the query faster. So, I have to complete all the processing inside the database and extract only the documents necessary for my purposes.

In this way, I would not face the memory limit not time limit even MongoDB processed the required data in 1s-2s.

here is my modified code.

```
return $collection->aggregate([
                [
                    '$match' => [
                        'created_at' => [
                            '$gte' => Carbon::parse($this->range[0])->startOfDay()->toDateTimeString(),
                            '$lte' => Carbon::parse($this->range[1])->addDay()->startOfDay()->toDateTimeString(),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id' => [
                            'user_id' => '$user_id',
                            'date' => ['$dateToString' => ['format' => '%Y-%m-%d', 'date' => ['$toDate' => '$created_at']]],
                        ],
                        'employee_code' => ['$max' => '$user.code'],
                        'name' => ['$max' => '$user.name'],
                        'checkin_outlet' => ['$first' => '$department.name'],
                        'first_check_in' => ['$min' => '$created_at'],
                        'first_checkin_address' => ['$first' => '$department.address'],
                        'checkout_outlet' => ['$last' => '$department.name'],
                        'last_check_out' => ['$max' => '$checked_out_at'],
                        'last_checkout_address' => ['$last' => '$department.address'],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    '$project' => [
                        '_id' => 0,
                        'user_id' => '$_id.user_id',
                        'employee_code' => 1,
                        'name' => 1,
                        'date' => '$_id.date',
                        'checkin_outlet' => 1,
                        'first_check_in' => 1,
                        'first_checkin_address' => 1,
                        'checkout_outlet' => 1,
                        'last_checkout_address' => 1,
                        'last_check_out' => 1,
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    '$sort' => ['date' => 1,'user_id'=> 1],
                ],
            ]);
        });
```